# How to do a mass rename?

Tags: unix, shell, rename

I need to rename files names like this

```
transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id=XXXXX
```

to just this

```
XXXXX.txt
```

How can I do it?

I understand that i need more than one `mv` command because they are at least 25000 files.

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 53):

Easiest solution is to use  ["mmv"](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/mmv.1.html)

You can write:

```
mmv "long_name*.txt" "short_#1.txt"
```

Where the "#1" is replaced by whatever is matched by the first wildcard.
Similarly #2 is replaced by the second, etc.

So you do something like

```
mmv "index*_type*.txt" "t#2_i#1.txt"
```

To rename index1_type9.txt to t9_i1.txt

mmv is not standard in many Linux distributions but is easily found on the net.

Comment: The mmv command is missing the second wild card. It should be
mmv "index*type*.txt" "t#2_i#1.txt"

Comment: If this is your first time using mmv, it's best to first try mmv -n <match> <rewrite>, which will show you what it would do without rewriting anything.

Comment: This is a nice little tool.  I like that it has alias forms for copying, linking, and even appending files together.

Comment: Works great in Windows with Cygwin

Comment: Note that using multiple hashes requires surrounding quotes or `mmv` raises an error.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using zsh you can also do this:

```
autoload zmv
zmv 'transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id=(*)' '$1.txt'
```

Comment: He did? Do you mean the tag? It was not added by him

Comment: Even if he's using bash he can always just run zsh and then use this answer.

Answer (score 13):

You write a fairly simple shell script in which the trickiest part is munging the name.

The outline of the script is easy (bash syntax here):

```
for i in 'transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id='*
do
    mv $i <modified name>
done
```

Modifying the name has many options.  I think the easiest is probably an awk one-liner like

```
`echo $i  |  awk -F'=' '{print $4}'`
```

so...

```
for i in 'transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id='*
do
    mv $i `echo $i |  awk -F'=' '{print $4}'`.txt 
done
```

#### update

Okay, as pointed out below, this won't necessarily work for a large enough list of files; the * will overrun the command line length limit.  So, then you  use:

```
$ find . -name 'transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id=*' -prune -print |
while read
do
    mv $reply `echo $reply |  awk -F'=' '{print $4}'`.txt 
done
```

Comment: there is a command for this called 'rename' in most linux distros. See briens answer.

Comment: Maybe so, but not all UNIX systems (not on my Mac for example) *and* this is a general pattern that can be applied to other issues.

Comment: At least in Bash and Dash, a `for` loop over a glob (or any builtin, at that) is not subject to "command line too long" limitation, so your first approach would also work for a very long list of files; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33619281/3266847).

Answer (score 5):

Try the [rename command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename)

Or you could pipe the results of an ls into a perl regex.

Comment: And how exactly do you do that with the `rename` command along?

Comment: like this:

rename transform.php\?dappName\=Test\&transformer\=YAML\&v_id\= '' transform.php*

Comment: @8jean: As I understand the question the result should be: s/.*?v_id=(.*)/$1.txt/. I don't see that in your comment.

Comment: Ah, I missed the '.txt' extension. Seems like there's no easy way to add that using "rename".

Answer (score 4):

You may use whatever you want to transform the name (perl, sed, awk, etc.). I'll use a python one-liner:

```
for file in 'transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id='*; do 
    mv $file `echo $file | python -c "print raw_input().split('=')[-1]"`.txt;
done
```

Here's the same script entirely in Python:

```
import glob, os
PATTERN="transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id=*"

for filename in glob.iglob(PATTERN):
      newname = filename.split('=')[-1] + ".txt"
      print filename, '==>', newname
      os.rename(filename, newname)
```

Side note: you would have had an easier life saving the pages with the right name while grabbing them...

Comment: Hah hah, my awk program is shorter. ;-)

Comment: Right :) awk is perfect for this kinds of jobs. Unfortunately, neither your sh script nor mine will work for 100000 files (there's a limit to a command line length, and the * may break such limit). If this is the case, rename or a dedicate script are better solutions.

Comment: @Federico: I'd add that the Python script (`glob.iglob()`) has a better chance to work for 100000 files.

Answer (score 4):

```
find -name '*v_id=*' | perl -lne'rename($_, qq($1.txt)) if /v_id=(\S+)/'
```

Comment: We could practically make a web page devoted to various ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

[vimv](https://github.com/thameera/vimv) lets you rename multiple files using Vim's text editing capabilities.

Entering `vimv` opens a Vim window which lists down all files and you can do pattern matching, visual select, etc to edit the names. After you exit Vim, the files will be renamed.

[Disclaimer: I'm the author of the tool]

Comment: You should point out that *you* wrote this tool, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94022/how-can-i-link-to-an-external-resource-in-a-community-friendly-way

Answer (score 0):

I'd use [ren-regexp](https://github.com/msabramo/ren-regexp), which is a Perl script that lets you mass-rename files very easily.

```
21:25:11 $ ls
transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id=12345

21:25:12 $ ren-regexp 's/transform.php.*v_id=(\d+)/$1.txt/' transform.php*

  transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id=12345
1 12345.txt


21:26:33 $ ls
12345.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

This should also work:

prfx='transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id='

ls $prfx* | sed s/$prfx// | xargs -Ipsx mv "$prfx"psx psx

Answer (score -1):

this [renamer](https://github.com/75lb/renamer) command would do it:

```
$ renamer --regex --find 'transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id=(\w+)' --replace '$1.txt' *
```

Answer (score -10):

Ok, you need to be able to run a windows binary for this.

But if you can run [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), do this:

1. Select all files with *, and hit **ctrl-M**
2. In the **Search** field, paste "transform.php?dappName=Test&transformer=YAML&v_id="

   (Leave **Replace** empty)
3. Press **Start**

It doesn't get much simpler than that.
You can also rename using regular expressions via this dialog, and you see a realtime preview of how your files are going to be renamed.

Comment: I'm accessing unix systems from my windows desktop all the time... Just suggesting how I would've solved this.

Comment: Whoa, after all these years i'm still getting downvotes for this one. :)