# How can I batch rename files?

Tags: windows, rename

I'm looking for a script (Perl, Python or batch would be fine) that will go through a designated file tree and renames all the child files.

For example, `Folder1>File1.anytype` becomes `Folder1>Folder1File1.anytype`.

Thanks

Comment: Why was this retagged not programming related?

Comment: It was probably tagged as not programming related because you appear to just be looking for existing software to accomplish a task and don't intend to do any programming yourself.

Comment: you can remove the tag if you don't like it.

Comment: Which system other than PrimeOS (from a very long time ago - circa 1980 when I encountered it) uses '>' to separate components of a path name.

Comment: Good point Leffler, I didn't mean to imply it was syntax, I will avoid that in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention a batch file, which probably means that you are on Windows (I assume you refer to a .bat file). If you're on a unix system, give this a shot:

```
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -exec sh -c "mv {} \`dirname {}\`/\`dirname {} | sed 's/^\.//' | sed 's/\///g'\`\`basename {}\`" \;
```

Alternatively, this Python 3 program may do the trick (should also work on Windows...):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.0

import os
import sys 

def raise_error(e):
    raise e

def full_split(path):
    head, tail = os.path.split(path)

    if head:
        return full_split(head) + [tail]

    return [tail]

def main(args):
    if len(args) != 1:
         print("Please specify one target directory", file=sys.stderr)
         sys.exit(1)

    os.chdir(args[0])
    for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk('.', onerror=raise_error):
        for f in filenames:
            old = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            new = os.path.join(dirpath, ''.join(full_split(dirpath[2:]) + [f]))
            os.rename(old, new)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The directory layout before:

```
.:
Abc  Def

./Abc:
Foo2.bar  Foo.bar

./Def:
Baz2.quux  Baz.quux  Ghi

./Def/Ghi:
Bar2.foo  Bar.foo
```

The directory layout after:

```
.:
Abc  Def

./Abc:
AbcFoo2.bar  AbcFoo.bar

./Def:
DefBaz2.quux  DefBaz.quux  Ghi

./Def/Ghi:
DefGhiBar2.foo  DefGhiBar.foo
```

Comment: Yes, I am on a windows machine.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I'm afraid in that case I cannot be of any help. I'll leave the answer here for future reference.

Comment: Ok, I may be of some help after all. Give the Python version a try :)

Answer (score 1):

The best batch renamer is [mmv](http://debaday.debian.net/2007/06/13/mmv-mass-moving-and-renaming-files/).

And see also [How to do a mass rename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417916/how-to-do-a-mass-rename)

Answer (score 0):

you could give a try to batchrename: http://batchrename.foryoursoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve such renames by using a nested for loop at the command line.. albeit a little ugly:

```
for /D %d in (*) do for %f in ("%d\*.*") do move "%f" "%d\%~nd%~nf"
```

If you wish to put the above command in a batch script, repeat each % characters once.

```
for /D %%d in (*) do for %%f in ("%%d\*.*") do move "%%f" "%%d\%%~nd%%~nf"
```

To understand what the above command does, consult `FOR /?` at the command line.

I feel like Batch is so arcane these days I need to preserve the BAT wisdom somehow... :-)

I'm kidding :-).. but the command does work, I've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty trivial in Perl using [File::Find](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/lib/File/Find.pm) and [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/~nwclark/perl-5.8.9/lib/File/Copy.pm)