# what is the best way to rename a set of files using a regex?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, terminal, command-line-arguments

I have a directory full of files name: "file1.mp4.mp4 file1.mp4.mp4 file1.mp4.mp4 ...".

I would like to rename all of them using find from "file1.mp4.mp4" to "file1.mp4" and some other bash tools it would look something like this but with a regular expression:

> find . -name "*.mp4" |xargs echo -0

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/417916/900873

Answer (score 2):

Use rename. If all the files are in the same directory, you can do this:

```
rename 's/\.mp4.mp4$/.mp4/' *.mp4.mp4
```

Otherwise you might want something like:

```
rename 's/\.mp4.mp4$/.mp4/' `find . -name "*.mp4.mp4"`
```

Also, to see what would happen when you run `rename`, just to debug the statement, do this:

```
rename --no-act 's/\.mp4.mp4$/.mp4/' *.mp4.mp4
```

This even works if the filename contains a space, for example:

```
$ touch foo.mp4.mp4
$ touch "bar baz.mp4.mp4"
$ ls
bar baz.mp4.mp4  foo.mp4.mp4
$ rename  's/\.mp4.mp4$/.mp4/' *.mp4.mp4
$ ls
bar baz.mp4  foo.mp4
$
```

Comment: what `rename` command is this? mine doesn't work with 's/\.mp4.mp4$/.mp4/' or recognise `--no-act`.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 11.11. As far as I know, `rename` comes as standard in the version of BASH that ships with Ubuntu. If you have a look at your man page, perhaps the syntax of your `rename` is different to mine?

Comment: the problem with your solution is that when there is a space in the file name it will not work.

Comment: It does on my machine; I've edited the answer to add a suitable example.

Comment: The program rename isn't part of the Bash, but part of a Perl package.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know.

Comment: It is part of the `File::Rename` Perl package: http://perladvent.org/2011/2011-12-18.html

Answer (score 2):

Or try this simple bash command in a loop?

```
mv /path/to/file.{mp4.mp4, mp4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
for file in /path/to/dir/*.mp4; do 
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the [`rename`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) command? If so, you can try:

```
rename .mp4 "" *.mp4.mp4
```

This will remove the final `.mp4` suffix from all files with extension `.mp4.mp4` in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.mp4.mp4' -exec echo mv {} \`dirname {}/\`/\`basename {} .mp4\` \; > mp4.sh && ./mp4.sh && rm mp4.sh
```

Comment: the problem with your solution is that when there is a space in the file name it will not work.

Comment: Which is quite consistent with the OQ, changes are trivial if needed.