# Rename multiple file names with bash shell

Tags: bash, shell

We have wrong file names like file1@x2.png , it should be like file1@2x~ipad.png.

Not sure if this is proper place for me to raise this question. How to write the simple bash shell script to convert such file name from the wrong to the expected.

Comment: are you saying that you need to rename a bunch of files to include `~ipad` before the extension if that part is not there ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a mass rename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417916/how-to-do-a-mass-rename).  There are also over 3000 other questions found with the search `[shell] rename file`.

Answer (score 3):

using **bash**, although this can be translated to sh/POSIX easily

```
for file in *; do
    [[ "$file" =~ @2x~ipad\.png$ ]] || mv "$file" "${file%@*}@2x~ipad.png"
done
```

---

if files are not just `png`s then use this (extension agnostic), assuming a 3 character extension.

```
for file in *; do
    [[ "$file" =~ @2x~ipad\.[[:alpha:]]{3}$ ]] || mv "$file" "${file%@*}@2x~ipad.${file##*.}"
done
```

---

if those files are not grouped under some dir then try to `find` them recursively under a specified root dir

```
while read -r file; do
    [[ "$file" =~ @2x~ipad\.[[:alpha:]]{3}$ ]] || mv "$file" "${file%@*}@2x~ipad.${file##*.}"
done < <(find /path/to/root/dir/to/look/under -type -f -name "*.png")
```

Comment: Good answer. He also wanted `x2` converted to `2x` so something like  `${file%x2.*}2x~ipad.${file##*.}`  will be requred.

Comment: good catch, didn't see that in the question. the file form should be cleared up though. I cant keep guessing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a script; try `mmv`:

```
mmv "*.png" "#1~ipad.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

`mv file1@x2.png file1@2x~ipad.png`
You can use `man mv` for help.

Comment: yes, hundreds maybe. And need find them first, and convert them.

Comment: so the location is not fixed ? those files are not grouped under some dir ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `prename` (comes with `perl`) to do this easily for lots of files:

```
prename 's/x2\.png/2x~ipad.png/' *.png
```