# unix command to change file name

Tags: shell

I have to change 
`<<STORE>>SA_MASTER_YYYMMDDHHMMSS.dat` file name to 
`SA_MASTERYYYMMDDHHMMSS.<<STORE>>`. Please tell me the command in unix to achieve this

for example
`0001.SAMASTER_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.DAT` should be changed to `SAMASTER_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.1` ie if the store has leading zero(0001) i have to eliminate the zeros(1)

Comment: The command is `mv`. Use `man mv` to see how it works

Comment: I think that you should re-word your question.  As it stands, it isn't a programming question but I guess that you want to use shell script to do this without doing each file manually.

Answer (score 2):

use `mv`.

e.G. `mv 0001.SAMASTER_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.DAT  SAMASTER_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.1`

For the interpretation you will need to write some script.

See [How to do a mass rename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417916/how-to-do-a-mass-rename) for further answers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the direct method is using `mv`. However, if you want to rename a lot of files' names, you need write a program, you need `sed`,`cut` and so on