# How to change the names of different type of files? (shell)

Tags: shell

Easy question for the wise. I have a bunch of files with the same name but different extensions, e.g:

```
file1.a
file1.b
file1.c
```

and I want to rename all of them to

```
name.a
name.b
name.c
```

How can I do this? thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a mass rename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417916/how-to-do-a-mass-rename)

Comment: what about when you reach z letter and you have yet some file to rename?

Answer (score 0):

So as BMW pointed out, there is another similar question ([How to do a mass rename?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417916/how-to-do-a-mass-rename) )

Just for the sake of it I will put the answer here:

To rename files with different extension you can do the following:

```
mmv "file1.*" "name.#1"
```

Thanks!